# Java ProcessBuilder execute multiple commands in sequence on same Java program

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

I am new to process building and I am trying to get a java program that will call another java program that expects inputs before printing. After looking through stackoverflow it seems I need a processbuilder for each command and for each process. I am unsure if the flowing process will be interacting with the java program launched? Currently the program doesn't throw any errors but I am not getting the final print. I have provided both programs.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static void main(String args[]){
            Scanner  sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            sc.nextLine();
            sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("you have done it");
    }
}
```

```
public class test2 {


    public static void main(String args[]){
        Process process;
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java -jar Test.jar");
        try {
            process = pb.start();
            process.waitFor();
            ProcessBuilder pb1 = new ProcessBuilder("no");
            Process process1 = pb1.start();
            process1.waitFor();
            ProcessBuilder pb2 = new ProcessBuilder("no");
            Process process2;
            process2 = pb2.start();

            process2.waitFor();
            System.out.println(process2.getInputStream());
            
        }catch(Exception e){

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Every process (any executable/library that can run) has 1) output stream 2) error output stream 3) input stream. If you want to 'interact' with the process you created, simple write to its input stream (which for you is an OutputStream): `OutputStream outStream = process.getOutputStream()`. Write the text there like this: `outStream.write("no\n".getBytes());` I don't have an IDE available atm, but this should do it. Don't forget the **\n** at the end, this simulates an enter key press. For Windows apps it might also be **\r\n** (bytes 13 10).

Comment: As mentioned, you need to read the *output* stream. Don't [do this](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/94-ignoring-exceptions-is-dangerous)
Also what is the application 'no'? Does it have output?